# What datatype to use when storing latitude and longitude data in SQL databases?

Tags: sql, database, geocoding, latitude-longitude

When storing latitude or longitude data in an ANSI SQL compliant database, what datatype would be most appropriate? Should `float` be used, or `decimal`, or ...?

I'm aware that Oracle, MySql, and SQL Server have added some special datatypes specifically for handling geo data, but I'm interested in how you would store the information in a "plain vanilla" SQL database.

Comment: Atul is right, it isn't the same question also because the other one specifies that calculations will be made on lat/lng. I just realized that my answer from the other one is best suited here, so please have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25120203/1226018

Answer (score 621, accepted):

For latitudes use: `Decimal(8,6)`, and longitudes use: `Decimal(9,6)`

If you're not used to precision and scale parameters, here's a format string visual:

Latitude and Longitude
`##.######` and `###.######`

To 6 decimal places should get you to around ~10cm of accuracy on a coordinate.

Comment: +1: Avoid round-off error weirdness by using a fixed number of decimal places.

Comment: For their purposes Wikipedia suggests: "Avoid excessive precision (0.0001° is <11 m, 1′′ is <31 m)."
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Obtaining_geographic_coordinates
To make my fields extra precise, I've also decided to use six digits right of the decimal mark, and three on the left. I'm glad this answer confirms it was a good decision.

Comment: Check the last answer but one in this [article](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/b928b5fbc5351821). The user William explains very well what happen with precision while you get far from the equator.

Comment: Also, if you are not going to operate with the numbers, consider storing them as a string. Using `varchar(20)` would be extra precise, and also cheap in storage space.

Comment: That's funny, was just checking that I used a good value DECIMAL(9,6) in the DB, but it's interfacing via NodeJS (which xfers as a float value tot he db anyway) so wanted to double-check.

Comment: (8,6) for latitudes and (9,6) for longitudes

Comment: why latitude (8,6) and Longitudes (9.6)... ?, any reason ?, why not both (9.6) ?

Comment: @Makito latititudes go from -90 to 90 degrees...so only need 2 places left of decimal point...

Comment: @Throoze Can you explain the reasoning behind suggesting `varchar(20)`? I won't be doing any operations, other than sending co-ordinates to Google Maps API, so am curious on the benefits of using `VARCHAR(20)` instead of `DECIMAL(9,6)`. Thank you!

Comment: @Shiva well geolocation datatypes are useful only if you are going to operate with them with any GIS driver or app. But if you only intend to store them, a string is more than enough. Eitherways, if you need to do some fancy operations with the values stored, take a look at [this article](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/b928b5fbc5351821) where they elaborate more on precision and using these values in a javascript app. It really is up to you I guess. Remember that Google maps API uses Json objects, so for them everything is a string.

Comment: With regards to the suggestions to store as VARCHAR, doesn't it actually use more space than a precision 9 decimal? -176.824107 in DECIMAL(9,6) would take 5 bytes while as a VARCHAR it would take 11 bytes (in UTF-8).

Comment: A very niche case but the Australian Beuro of Statistics provides accuracy to 8 decimal places, so I use Dec 11,8

Answer (score 12):

EDIT (14+ years later):  Don't use float for precision-based numeric values.  dotjoe's answer to use Decimal(9,6) is perfect.

Leaving my old answer here for laughs:

> We use float, but any flavor of numeric with 6 decimal places should
> also work.  **- me, 2009**

Comment: A calculation might introduce extra digits which would only be noise.  Also the decimal-to-binary transformation will make the final decimal place suspicious and possibly wrong.  Fine for some purposes.  Lousy for navigation.

Comment: I don't think suggesting float deserves a down-rate - you made me second-guess and search elsewhere for an answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551894/whats-the-best-way-to-store-co-ordinates-longitude-latitude-from-google-maps

Comment: The question is about storing. A 32-bit float is the most efficient way to store. If you need to do a lot of calculations, and can show that rounding errors matter, then cast to 64-bit float first.

Comment: 32-bit float has 24 bits of precision, which amounts to 0.000005° degrees of precision for longitudes around 180°.  Near equator, that would be 1 meter. Depends on your application, but if you're comparing GPS device accuracy in Hawaii, don't store your coordinates in floats.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a decimal with the proper precision for your data.

Answer (score 2):

In vanilla Oracle, the feature called LOCATOR (a crippled version of Spatial) requires that the coordinate data be stored using the datatype of NUMBER (no precision).  When you try to create Function Based Indexes to support spatial queries it'll gag otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily store a lat/lon decimal number in an unsigned integer field, instead of splitting them up in a integer and decimal part and storing those separately as somewhat suggested here using the following conversion algorithm:

as a stored mysql function:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`r`@`l` FUNCTION `PositionSmallToFloat`(s INT) 
RETURNS decimal(10,7)
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN if( ((s > 0) && (s >> 31)) , (-(0x7FFFFFFF - 
(s & 0x7FFFFFFF))) / 600000, s / 600000)
```

and back

```
CREATE DEFINER=`r`@`l` FUNCTION `PositionFloatToSmall`(s DECIMAL(10,7)) 
RETURNS int(10)
DETERMINISTIC
RETURN s * 600000
```

That needs to be stored in an **unsigned int(10)**, this works in mysql as well as in sqlite which is typeless.

through experience, I find that this works really fast, if all you need to to is store coordinates and retrieve those to do some math with.

in php those 2 functions look like

```
function LatitudeSmallToFloat($LatitudeSmall){
   if(($LatitudeSmall>0)&&($LatitudeSmall>>31)) 
     $LatitudeSmall=-(0x7FFFFFFF-($LatitudeSmall&0x7FFFFFFF))-1;
   return (float)$LatitudeSmall/(float)600000;
}
```

and back again:

```
function LatitudeFloatToSmall($LatitudeFloat){
   $Latitude=round((float)$LatitudeFloat*(float)600000);
   if($Latitude<0) $Latitude+=0xFFFFFFFF;
   return $Latitude;
}
```

This has some added advantage as well in term of creating for example memcached unique keys with integers. (ex: to cache a geocode result). Hope this adds value to the discussion.

Another application could be when you are without GIS extensions and simply want to keep a few million of those lat/lon pairs, you can use partitions on those fields in mysql to benefit from the fact they are integers:

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `Locations` (
  `lat` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `lon` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `location` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`lat`,`lon`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `index_location` (`locationText`(30))
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!50100 PARTITION BY KEY ()
PARTITIONS 100 */
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the operations you'll be needing to do most frequently.

If you need the full value as a decimal number, then use decimal with appropriate precision and scale. Float is way beyond your needs, I believe.

If you'll be converting to/from degºmin'sec"fraction notation often, I'd consider storing each value as an integer type (smallint, tinyint, tinyint, smallint?).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you asked how to store Latitude/Longitude and my answer is: Don't, you might consider using the [WGS 84](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Geodetic_System) ( in Europe [ETRS 89](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Terrestrial_Reference_System_1989) ) as it is the standard for Geo references.

But that detail aside I used a User Defined Type in the days before SQL 2008 finally include geo support.

Comment: I am curious, can you remember what you meant when you suggested to not save the latitude and longitude? What were you thinking you would save instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what Kasper is saying here. Lat/Long is a position format (equivalent to UTM, MGRS, NZTM etc), whereas WGS84 is a datum - a reference system that position coordinates are applied to. You need to know *both* your coordinates and which datum you are using, although for online use it is almost always WGS84.

Comment: Yeah, this is a really unhelpful answer to say "don't" and then not elaborate on their reasoning.