# Precision of GEOMETRY object?

Tags: mysql, sql, geospatial, precision

I am storing my Lat and Long values in the GEOMETRY type within MySql.  Unfortunately it seems to be rounding to *4 decimal places*, which according to this [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees) isn't very accurate.  I want to use the Geospatial functions in mySql, but it seems to be lacking the precision I need.  Any ideas what I can do?  Can I increase the precision, or am I forced to store it as a double/float instead?  If I want to use any of the other functionality in the GIS portion of mySql, will these values also be rounded (even if I store in seperate fields as another datatype)?

Comment: This *might* get a more useful response over at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The reason might be the display precision loss of Navicat (Maybe due to setting or old version?). I have met the exactly same issue while processing multipolygons. And it turned out that it actually store more than 4 decimal places in the db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Alexey Botchkov:

> ...we use DOUBLE to store spatial coordinates which means 15 digit precision.

Source: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34075 (at the bottom).

So GEOMETRY types are already stored as doubles, no need to do that yourself.

Comment: But Actually We can store 14 digit in the database without any problem. Its just rounding off the 15th digit. As per my use case, I have to store Polygon shapes. In some cases, Vertex(lattitude, longitude) of the Polygon goes 15 to 20 digit precision. Is there any way to store these extra digit precision ?

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at: [What datatype to use when storing latitude and longitude data in SQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196415/what-datatype-to-use-when-storing-latitude-and-longitude-data-in-sql-databases)

Decimal(9,6) would do and it provides an accuracy/error of about 1m.

Comment: Your answer related to a `Point` while the OP question is about `Geometry`