# Map marker doesn't point to exact location

Tags: android, google-maps

So I'm storing markers from my map into a sqlite database. I am trying to query the markers by latitude and longitude. So for testing I am adding the marker to a specific location. When I check the markers position it gives me another location. What is causing this?

```
    private void drawMarker(LatLng point, String title, String snippet){
    // Creating an instance of MarkerOptions
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    // Setting latitude and longitude for the marker
    LatLng l = new LatLng(37.52100000000001, -77.44800000000001);
    markerOptions.position(l);
    markerOptions.title(title);
    markerOptions.snippet(snippet);
    // Adding marker on the Google Map
    googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions); 
}
```

This is the code to extract the marker position

```
    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
      marker1 = marker;     
      LatLng mlatlong = marker1.getPosition();
      markerLat = Double.toString(mlatlong.latitude);
      markerLng = Double.toString(mlatlong.longitude);
      latitude = mlatlong.latitude;
      longitude = mlatlong.longitude;
      Log.i("Marker", mlatlong.latitude +","+mlatlong.longitude);
      markerDialog();
        }

    });
```

This gives me the position 
06-20 21:53:52.447: I/Marker(15221): 37.52100000569583,-77.44800008833408

Comment: What do you see if you print LatLng l = new LatLng(37.52100000000001, -77.44800000000001); ?

Comment: Hi David, have you found the solution of getting the exact LatLng values from a Marker? I have the same problem.

Comment: So far it has been close enough to what I need. I was just curious to why it was happening. So to answer your question, No I didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: Thank you anyway. It is not enough for me because I need to compare exactly the position. I'm pretty annoyed with this """"bug"""". I'll keep searching...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, and most other languages you'll come accross, `double` is not stored as a precise value.

You can read more [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3).

Also, it shouldn't really matter the locations you posted are [extremely close to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167604/how-accurately-should-i-store-latitude-and-longitude).

Comment: i don't notice any variation in position. the problem comes when I query my sqlite for that exact position. It doesn't find it because its saves as the exact position that I told it.

Comment: I would avoid doing that and use some kind of key or other identifier.

Comment: I considered querying the title but its possible that the user could use the same title for multiple markers.