# Losing decimal places in hive tables

Tags: hive, azure-hdinsight

I created a float columns for a hive table. I then uploaded some lat/lng data:

```
-74.223827433599993,40.698842158200002
-117.57601661229999,34.044852414099999
-81.055917609600002,29.239413820500001
-80.369884327199998,25.789129988199999
```

When I query the data out or into another table, the rounding is significant:

```
-74.22383,40.69884
-117.57602,34.044853
-81.055916,29.239414
-80.36988,25.78913
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the `DOUBLE` data type rather than `FLOAT`.

BTW the 6th decimal place corresponds to 0.1m at the equator which is possibly much less than the margin of error on your data! (See the answer to [this question.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167604/how-accurately-should-i-store-latitude-and-longitude)