# How to get google maps zoom in meters

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

i'm programming a application using google maps and i need to send to my webservice my actual location with latitude, longitude and distance in meters, i need to obtain the google maps zoom in meters, but i don't know how to do it..

I'm using this method but i don't know how to convert the zoom value to meter to send.

```
mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom
```

For example, i need to zoom in or zoom out on the google maps and convert the zoom value to meters, 10000 meters, 20000 meters, etc..

Answer (score 0):

I think that you don't need to put the zoom at the meter level to get the distance in meters. You can work with the precision of the latitude and longitude. With 5 decimal points you can have aproximately 1 meter scale.

Ref.:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_degrees#Precision

[How accurately should I store latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167604/how-accurately-should-i-store-latitude-and-longitude)

Comment: I guess you do not understand what I need. When I pinch the zoom on the map I need to calculate the distance between the camera and the ground to send to my webservice to calculate and return the markers.