# MySQL precision DECIMAL(13,9) for longitude

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to update a row in the MySQL table, the data of the column is `-122.333351900` and it already exists, so there is no problem on its length not matching the data type and its length.

But when I run a UPDATE sql command it fails with

```
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'longitude' at row 1
```

I don't understand why its wrong? It already has inserted this value and now when I run an UPDATE command it fails with an error!

Comment: Do you have a trigger on that table?

Comment: @juergend you are my angel! Please put that as an answer and I can accept.... The trigger was having a wrong datatype and hence the issue.

Comment: For what it's worth, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167604/how-accurately-should-i-store-latitude-and-longitude Using precision of DECIMAL(13,9) is measuring longitude down to the tenths of millimeters! :-)

Comment: I can insert that value into a column of that type. There's got to be something else in play here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your table if it has a trigger on it. A trigger runs right before or after the update/insert on a table.

If it contains an error it looks like the update is going wrong when actually a related trigger fails.

Comment: I had a trigger and the column in the archive table was having different DECIMAL definition