# EF5, SQL Server, Longitude and Latitude

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, latitude-longitude

I found that the best type to store lat and long in SQL Server is decimal (9,6) (ref. [What datatype to use when storing latitude and longitude data in SQL databases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196415/what-datatype-to-use-when-storing-latitude-and-longitude-data-in-sql-databases)) and so I did

```
AddColumn("dbo.Table", "Latitude", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 9, scale: 6));
AddColumn("dbo.Table", "Longitude", c => c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 9, scale: 6));
```

SQL seems ok, everything is working, BUT when I insert / update a value, i.e.

```
lat = 44.5912853
```

it is saved like this:

```
44.590000
```

I checked the flow, and just before the update, my entity contains the correct value, so I don't think is related to my code, but to some round that EF / SQL does. Do you have any idea to avoid this?

**UPDATE**

```
update [dbo].[Breweries]
set [RankId] = @0, 
[Name] = @1, 
[Foundation] = null, 
[DirectSale] = @2, 
[OnlineSale] = @3, 
[StreetAddress] = @4, 
[StreetAddress1] = null, 
[ZIP] = @5, 
[City] = @6, 
[Province] = @7, 
[CountryCode] = @8, 
[Latitude] = @9, 
[Longitude] = @10, 
[PIVA] = null, 
[CodFiscale] = null
where ([BreweryId] = @11)
```

[image]

**POCO entity**

```
[Table("Breweries")]
public class Brewery : ABrewery 
{
  ....
  public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
  public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

**SQL Profiler**

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[Breweries]
set [RankId] = @0, [Name] = @1, [Foundation] = null, [DirectSale] = @2, [OnlineSale] = @3, [StreetAddress] = @4, [StreetAddress1] = null, [ZIP] = @5, [City] = @6, [Province] = @7, [CountryCode] = @8, [Latitude] = @9, [Longitude] = @10, [PIVA] = null, [CodFiscale] = null
where ([BreweryId] = @11)
',N'@0 int,@1 nvarchar(128),@2 bit,@3 bit,@4 nvarchar(256),@5 varchar(16),@6 nvarchar(64),@7 nvarchar(64),@8 nvarchar(128),@9 decimal(18,2),@10 decimal(18,2),@11 int',@0=2,@1=N'Davide',@2=0,@3=0,@4=N'Via Moscardini, 24',@5='zip',@6=N'city',@7=N'province',@8=N'ITA',

@9=44.59,@10=11.05,@11=2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently [this guy had the exact same problem](http://www.gavindraper.co.uk/2011/07/11/entity-framework-code-first-rounding-decimal-model-properties/) and solved it thus:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>().Property(a => a.Latitude).HasPrecision(18, 9);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Activity>().Property(a => a.Longitude).HasPrecision(18, 9);
}
```

Although you may want to look at using the [spatial data types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933790.aspx) (particularly [`geography`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx)) in SQL Server 2008 and later.

Comment: I saw "HasPrecision", but even if I add the namespace, I get an error when I try to use it (method not found)

Comment: Does it get to `Property` okay?

Comment: yes, neither the intellisense found it .. I thought that was an old version and I tried differently .. but I'll try again why I don't have this prop.

Comment: found it! and solve .. I don't know exactly why, I have a separeted project to collect all the EntityTypeConfiguration (that is probably useless but I feel more organize) .. in this project HasPrecision isn't found (I'll investigate and report here why) .. but if I set the property in the datacontext, I can do it .. and fix the problem

Comment: I was going to say you might have to cast it from `Primitive...` to `Decimal...` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.primitivepropertyconfiguration(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can use **DbGeography** type for storing Latitude and Longitude.

```
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

public class Test
{
    public DbGeography Location { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. I just purchased a Zip code database and it stores all latitude and longitude values as decimal(12,6) data type. I don't think this is going to radically change your results though.
2. I would check the exact SQL being sent to your SQL Server. You can then check to see where the rounding is occurring. You can check the SQL being sent by grabbing the output from EF or using SQL Profiler. My guess is that it's occuring in your C# code.

Also, it might be useful to see your table schema and your domain entity.

Comment: I posted the screenshot of the db table and what I see in Intellitrace (not very usefull I think, if you tell me how to better grab the output from EF, I'll post it)

Comment: What about your C# entity?

Comment: I was able to profile, as you can see, the values are already rounded before the update

Comment: Fix using the HasPrecision method in the modelbuilder config. but anyway thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the data type of these fields as Float:

```
 Latitude float,
 Longitude float
```