# SQL Server Decimal - Why is my decimal value only capturing two decimal places after the decimal? Yes, it's decimal(18,5)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'll just start by saying I have my decimal data type defined as decimal(18,5):

[image]

The values coming from my app before it hits the database are:

[image]

So as you can see so far, everything looks good.  I should see a value of 0.47588 in my database table for column `Capsule105`.  But, after my record saves to the database, I look at the record it inserted- take a look at the last row:

[image]

The value shouldn't stop after two decimal places.  It should go to the very last decimal place defined in my database, right?

Here's my `InsertOrUpdate` method (came stock with the template in VS):

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(CalculatedResults calculatedresults)
{
    if (calculatedresults.Pk == default(int)) {
        // New entity
        context.CalculatedResults.Add(calculatedresults);
    } else {
        // Existing entity
        context.Entry(calculatedresults).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

I'm using Code First approach and generating my database from my models.

Any ideas what's going on here??? Please help!!

Comment: Can you show us the code, too?  How are you connecting to the repository?

Comment: What's the type of the C# `Capsule105`?

Comment: And how are you viewing the data?

Comment: @LinusCaldwell The type of Capsule105 in C# is decimal.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I'm saving these values to the database first, and displaying the result set from my model on my view.  The values I display on my view display correctly.  They just aren't saving to the database correctly... am I understanding you correct?

Comment: @MikeMarks: Well I would look in the database first - otherwise you don't know whether it's a problem of fetching back, or storing. (I suspect it's storing, but it doesn't hurt to check.)

Comment: Are you dividing or doing any other calculations on the data before inserting or updating? This will sometimes result in a loss of precision.

Comment: @Scotch No, I'm not.. The point where I showed what the values in C# are the values that get inserted into the database with no intermediary operations taking place... weird!!!

Comment: Did you set the precision: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040124/242520

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem, so maybe this helps: I had to specify the type in the `DbContext`. In my case, the field in the database was of type `Money`, and the C# type for the models property was `Decimal`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.Value).HasColumnType("Money");
```

Don't know, but maybe it works if you change that to "Decimal" or even "Decimal(18,5)" if that's possible. Or to pick up the comment of ta.speot:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.Value)
            .HasColumnType("Decimal")
            .HasPrecision(18, 5);
```

Comment: Thank you, what worked was: modelBuilder.Entity<CalculatedResults>().Property(a => a.Capsule105).HasPrecision(18, 5);

Comment: That sounds like your entity definition is wrong, or it would have done that for you.

Comment: @Bobson Well I wonder if the default precision is 2 for C# data type Decimal?  When I create my models I never have to define the precision.  I don't know, just an idea.

Comment: @MikeMarks - No, `decimal` holds 28 significant digits.

Answer (score 0):

@Mike Marks

you can resolve this issue like below changes into **OnModelCreating** method inside DBContext class

`protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Table1>().Property(a => a.price).HasPrecision(18, 5);
        }`

Comment: I can't quite see how this differs from the accepted answer from last year?