# How to correctly save acres as decimals from C# to SQL

Tags: c#, math, decimal

We store acreage of a parcel to 4 decimal places e.g. 1234.1234.I can easily set SQL to define a decimal to 4 places, but only two are being written to the database. For example if a user types 12.1234 into a field, the value that gets saved to SQL is 12.1200. Here is the code that reads and saves the data. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
decimal dec = Convert.ToDecimal(txtAcres.Text);
context.C_decP1GAcres = dec;
strStatusChange = strCurrentUserDisplayName + " changed Parcel 1 Gross Acres from " + 
    olddec.ToString("G") + " to " + dec.ToString("G");
```

I can only get it to display correctly when it is in string form. Note the code for strStatusChange. This writes a log and in that log it displays perfectly.

How should I fix the issue?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using and what's the type of the column you are saving the field on your database?

Comment: Can you let us know how your SQL column is defined (i.e., what are the values of X and Y in `columnName decimal (X, Y) [NOT] NULL`?  I'm guessing that `context.C_decP1GAcres` is an Entity Framework expression (where `context` is a db context).  Is this right?  Can you show us your full DB access code (you can skip the unimportant fields).  What is the type of `C_decP1GAcres `?

Comment: of course. SQL is 14.1 and the datatype is (decimal 12, 4)

Comment: ...and yes that is entity framework, that is pretty much it. I have a local variable that I populate with the record identifier so I can load at the start of an event and save changes at the end. What you see is the only code representing that field.

Comment: please use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16070337/9801177) as a reference to see if your problem gets fixed

Comment: @Ray.  Are you using an ORM?  I'd check every point of possible change on the tunnel from code to db.  Perhaps your ORM is truncating.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you Pietro, that looks like it will do the trick. I'll update in a bit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server Decimal - Why is my decimal value only capturing two decimal places after the decimal? Yes, it's decimal(18,5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070232/sql-server-decimal-why-is-my-decimal-value-only-capturing-two-decimal-places-a)

Answer (score 2):

Pietro's answer worked. In the dbcontextmap the field needed to be changed

from:
      this.Property(t => t.C_decP1GAcres).HasColumnName("_decP1GAcres");

to:
      this.Property(t => 
      t.C_decP1GAcres).HasColumnName("_decP1GAcres").HasPrecision(12, 4);

I will eventually put it into a partial class because this will be over written if I ever have to remap the database, but for now it works.