# Input string not in a correct format when trying to set a variable of type double equal to parsed coordinates?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am trying to set longitude and latitude variables (from a viewmodel) equal to longitude and latitude values fetched from a database table (note: within the database table, the longitude and latitude variables are of type "nvarchar(50)"). However, upon execution of that specific code, I get a system.formatException stating that "Input string was not in a correct format".

ViewModel Attributes:

```
public double Longitude { get; set; }
public double Latitude { get; set; }
```

Database Attributes:

[image]

The controller in which I assign the view model attributes to the passed database attributes:

```
 public JsonResult GetMarkers()
        {
            //Disable lazy loading
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            //Map marker section
            var DynamicMapMarkers = db.tblNpo.Include(zz => zz.tblVerification).Include(xx => xx.tblNpo_Type);

            //Set map marker values
            foreach (var item in DynamicMapMarkers)
            {
                DonatorUserViewModel MapMarkers = new DonatorUserViewModel();

                MapMarkers.NpoID = item.npo_id;
                MapMarkers.NpoName = item.npo_name;
                MapMarkers.NpoType = item.tblNpo_Type.description;
                MapMarkers.VerificationStatus = item.tblVerification.description;
                MapMarkers.Longitude = double.Parse(item.longitude); //this is where the error is thrown
                MapMarkers.Latitude = double.Parse(item.latitude);
                MapMarkerList.Add(MapMarkers);
            }

            var json = MapMarkerList;
            return Json(json, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Additionally. there is a chance that the value of item.longitude and item.latitude will come through as nothing (there wont be any data from tblNpo to fetch). Would this be a problem at all?

Comment: Parsing "nothing" as a double won't work because it isn't a valid representation of a number. If you need to handle invalid data, use `double.TryParse()`.

Comment: I have tried `double.TryParse()`, however i get the error "No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments".

Comment: Why are they "nvarchar(50)" in database if they are numbers?

Comment: @Evk should i maybe change it to a float?

Comment: @SeventhWarhawk That's because `TryParse` doesn't take one argument. It takes a minimum of two: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1#overloads

Comment: Some databases like sql server has native support for such data, for example "geography" type (more costly but you can perform a lot of operations on that data if you need them). Otherwise it is usually stored as decimals: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1196429/5311735