# SQL Spatial Query - Determine Which Polygon A Lat/Long Point Falls Into

Tags: sql, spatial-query

Via ArcMap, I imported a Feature Class into my SQL2019 Server. No issues and the polygons are displaying properly in the 'spatial results' tab when I check. Inside that feature class, there are three distinct shapes (Lets call the field tblGeo.AREA).

I have another table with LAT/LNG coordinate points (tblPoint.LAT, tblPoint.LNG).

Using the two tables (tblGeo and tblPoint), how can I determine which AREA field the coordinate falls into (if any)?

**tblGeo**:

| Field Name | Field Type | Sample |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GID | INT | 1,2,3... |
| SHAPE | GEOMETRY | 0x2569... or 0x110F... |
| GEOAREA | VARCHAR(50) | Washington, New York,... |

**tblPoint**:

| Field Name | Field Type | Sample |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PID | INT | 1,2,3... |
| LOCATION | VARCHAR(100) | White House |
| LAT | DECIMAL(9,6) | 38.897957 |
| LNG | DECIMAL(9,6) | -77.036560 |

**Desired Output**

| PID | Location | Lat | Lng | GeoArea |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | White House | 38.897957 | -77.036560 | Washington |
| 2 | Empire State Building | 40.748817 | -73.985428 | New York |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample input and output data would be nice.
You'll need to [convert `LAT` and `LNG` to a geometry point](https://lynnatsouthsidesoft.wordpress.com/2013/10/21/sql-server-latitude-longitude-conversion-to-geometry-and-geography/).
Assuming `LAT` and `LNG` are [`DECIMAL(9, 6)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196415/what-datatype-to-use-when-storing-latitude-and-longitude-data-in-sql-databases)...

```
select g.name as AreaName
, p.name as PointName

from tblGeo g
  right outer join tblPoint p on g.AREA.STContains(geometry::Point(p.LAT, p.LNG, 0)) = 1
```

I could check my work if you provided sample data.

Comment: I have added some table samples. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: So, did it work for you?  I can't test because the data you provided is not valid.  For example '0x2569...' is not a geometry.  Plus, your "sample" indicates you are using geometry, but your question says you're using geography.  Maybe create a db fiddle.

Comment: It did not work. The Feature Class data was imported through ArcMap and exists in the database as a GEOMETRY type, so I only assume that it imported correctly. There are some functions that work (ie: tblGeo.SHAPE.STCentroid() will give me the centroid of each geometry area). But can't figure out how to do the joins just yet ...

Comment: I updated my answer.  If you expect me to test this, please provide valid DML to generate sample data.

Comment: Got it to work using your code. The only missing part was the " = 1" in the join. Thank you for all the help.