# SQL 2012 Error in LEFT or SUBSTRING function

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, substring

I am trying to execute the following SQL query:

```
SELECT TMP.*,COUNT(*) OVER () AS rCount 
FROM (
    SELECT venueID, 
           venueName AS venueName, 
           venueSpanish AS spanish, 
           venueAddress + ', ' + venueCity + ', ' + venueState + ' ' + venueZip AS venueAddress, 
           venueLatLong AS coordinates, 
           CONVERT(VARCHAR, venueEventDate, 101) + ' @ ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,venueTime) AS dateAndTime, 
           SUBSTRING(venueLatLong, 1, CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong)-1) AS Lat, 
           SUBSTRING(venueLatLong, CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong) + 1, 1000) AS Lng, 
           (round(3959 * acos (cos(radians('35.0935409')) * 
                cos(radians(SUBSTRING(venueLatLong, 1, CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong)-1))) * 
                cos(radians(SUBSTRING(venueLatLong, CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong) + 1, 1000)) - 
                radians('-85.0856761')) + 
                sin(radians('35.0935409')) * 
                sin(radians(SUBSTRING(venueLatLong, 1, CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong)-1)))), 1, 1)) AS distance 
    FROM meetUpMarkers) TMP 
WHERE distance < 30
```

However, I am getting this as an error when doing so:

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>
> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Any help would be great to solve this issue!

Comment: You have values of `venueLatLong` that have no commas.

Comment: You may want to consider using SQL Server Spatial Data Types: http://stackoverflow.com/q/551894/3854195

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem could be with the arguments passed to the `substring` function. This condition is being repeated in the query.

```
CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong)
```

If the `venueLatLong` doesn't contain `,`, this argument to the `substring` is invalid.

This can be avoided by including a `where` clause.

```
WHERE CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong) > 0
```

Comment: Yeah it looks as though *some* records did not have "xx.xxxxxx,-xx.xxxxxxx" for lat/long so therefore it was throwing that error.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably this line:

```
SUBSTRING(venueLatLong, 1, CHARINDEX(',', venueLatLong)-1) AS Lat
```

there's no comma in `venueLatLong` and this results in `-1` for the length

Why don't you store Latitude and Longitude in two numeric columns instead of a VarChar?

Comment: Yeah it looks as though *some* records did not have "xx.xxxxxx,-xx.xxxxxxx" for lat/long so therefore it was throwing that error.